# Using a predicate to compare a value from a Json Array with a double

Tags: ios, json, nspredicate

I am trying to filter a filed of the dictionaries of a json array with a double. Doing it simply by:

```
double maxDistance=0.0003;
NSPredicate* nearPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Distance < %ld", maxDistance];
[jsonCloudArray filterUsingPredicate:nearPredicate];
```

produces crash:

> -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e0398f0

If instead I use the code from a sample I found on Stackoverflow:

```
NSLog(@"arrival %@", jsonCloudArray);
NSPredicate *nearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSDictionary *bindings)  {
     NSNumber *idNumber = dictionary[@"Distance"];
     BOOL result= [idNumber doubleValue] < maxDistance;
     NSLog(@"processing distance %f", [idNumber doubleValue]);
     return result;
}];
[jsonCloudArray filterUsingPredicate:nearPredicate];
```

I get a silent crash happening after having processed all the elements of the array, as I could see by comparing the two NSLog's.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily by using ***filteredArrayUsingPredicate*** as in:

```
double maxDistance=0.0003;
NSLog(@"arriva %@", jsonCloudArray);
NSPredicate *nearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSNumber *idNumber = dictionary[@"Distance"];
    BOOL result= [idNumber doubleValue] < maxDistance;
    NSLog(@"processing distance %f", [idNumber doubleValue]);
    return result;
}];
jsonCloudArray  = [[jsonCloudArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:nearPredicate] mutableCopy];
```

I have no crash any more.